# How to use receive POST data in asp.net web api?

Tags: c#-4.0, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've googled a whole day but still can't find the answer. I need to `POST` data via `jQuery.post` to `Web API MVC-4` but unable to. This is my routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and this is my `Controller` (the `GET` works!):

```
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    public void Post([FromBody]string data)
    {
        //body...
    }
```

This is the `jQuery.post:`

```
$.post('api/mycontroller', { key1: 'val1' });
```

Any idea ?

## Edit:

@Darin: I tried this:

```
public class UnitDetails{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public void Post(UnitDetails id) {
    //body...
}
```

and:

```
$.post('api/mycontroller', {id:'string1'});
```

But still I miss something.. it doesn't stop in `Post(...){...}`. Again - `Get(...){...}` does work.. ?

Comment: There are special routes for API controllers, recognizable by `MapHttpRoute` instead of `MapRoute`. By default, they're defined in App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs. What does this route configuration look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design and the only way to make this work with a primitive type such as a string is the following:

```
$.post('/api/mycontroller', '=' + encodeURIComponent('val1'));
```

So the body of the POST request must contain the following:

```
=val1
```

instead of:

```
data=val1
```

This has been discussed in [this thread](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/359687).

As an alternative you could define a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action take this view model as parameter:

```
public void Post(MyViewModel model)
{
    //body...
}
```

Contrary to primitive types, complex types use formatters instead of model binding. Here's [`an article`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx) which covers how does the Web API does parameter binding.

Comment: I tried what you suggested (see in the question's edit, above), with no success..

Comment: Rename your action parameter to something different than `id`. For example: `public void Post(UnitDetails details) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

You're posting to `api/mycontroller`. ASP.NET MVC automatically appends the name supplied with 'Controller', so it's looking for a controller named `mycontrollerController`. The name of your API controller is not mentioned in your post, but I suspect it's not that.

Assuming that your controller is named 'myController', try posting to `api/my`.

```
$.post('api/my', { id: 'string1' });
```